# double click a file to run a specific command

Tags: autorun

I'd like to new a file obtaining a cmd such as "sudo gedit filename". When I double click this file, the cmd in this file is executed. How to make it work? Thanks
And the OS is ubuntu 13.10

Comment: What is the exact purpose of this?? I'm pretty much unclear with what you require such script to do

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file for script..
A script should have in its first line the so called shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

So your overall script Should look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar JavaApplication3.jar
```

save your file now go to properties->permissions and check the "is Executable" option..
Make sure your file has the permission to be executed.

Now double click .........

its all done have fun